# Set imageView trough AsyncTask into a listView

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, imageview

I am trying to set the imageViews of my listView with an Asynctask.

The problem is the same as other users, when i scrolling fast the screen the pictures don´t set properly to the contacts and if I scroll up and down fast when I stop the imageViews changes continuosly until all the trheads end.

The code is below:

```
new CargarFotoSegundoPlano(imagenParcela).execute(Integer.parseInt(children.getIdContacto())); //this is the call to asynctask
```

class

```
public class CargarFotoSegundoPlano extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap>
{
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
    ImageView imageView;

    //String tag;
    public CargarFotoSegundoPlano(ImageView imageView)
    {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<>(imageView);
        this.imageView = imageView;
        //this.tag = imageView.getTag().toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params)
    {
        //imageView = (ImageView) params[0];
        Integer idLong = (Integer) params[0];
        return cargarFotoContacto(idLong); //this method return a bitmap
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        if (isCancelled())
        {
            bitmap = null;
            // imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        }
        if (imageViewReference != null)
        {
            ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null)
            {
                if (bitmap != null)
                {
                    Animation mover = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.difuminado_foto_mini);
                    imageView.startAnimation(mover);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
                else
                {
                    Drawable placeholder = imageView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fastcontacts);
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(placeholder);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Drawable placeholder = imageView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fastcontacts);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(placeholder);
        }
    }
}
```

This set correctly the image to the contacts that has photo but if the contact doesn't have photo get the photo of the other contact.

Any help will be welcome.

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

If you're starting an app from scratch I'd strongly suggest using some established library for image loading / caching, etc. Some of the best choices available are [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) (super simple to use) and [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) (bit trickier to use, but with more configuration options).

P.S. I just remembered what Boris Farber (Google Developer Advocate) says about image loading - "Use libraries. If you're doing it yourself from scratch, there's a fair chance you're doing something wrong/unefficient".

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but if I post a request here is because i don't want to use a library. 

This is the easiest way and I don't learn anything using it.

Reading the references of this kind of things in Android Developers my code isn't so far of the solution. 

I think that doing something in onPostExecute method the things gonna be ok.

I will continue by myself.

Thanks another time, warm regards!